# Appstore color and banner for certain apps

Tags: ios, app-store

I was browsing through the app store today and noticed a few apps (Instagram, Netflix and other supercell games) that had a page with custom font colors and the header seen below. Is something that is accessible to all developers or is this in beta or what? These are all on the top 144 apps so I was just curious to see if this could be done without having a very popular app or if this feature is only available to larger companies?

[[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a local iTunes team chooses to feature your app they ask you for special artwork.

This is not available to us mere mortals.